# Python - Indentation Error but not from mixing tabs and spaces

Tags: python-3.x

VSCode is giving me indentation errors on some python code. I have exhaustively checked my code to see if it is the ol' mixing tabs/spaces problem *(turning on `render white space` in Code, and pasting the code into NPP and turning on `View tabs and spaces` and regex searching for `\t` etc.)* But it's not. No tab chars anywhere.

So I am wondering if all functions must be indented from their calling function?

For example, is there anything wrong with this syntax?

```
from SGS_ExcelPrePythonPrep_funcs_ver0_01JD import *
def main():
    #some code
    myVar = func1(data)
    #more code

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()

#------ separate file: SGS_ExcelPrePythonPrep_funcs_ver0_01JD.py ------

def func1(data):
    #more code
    newVar = func2(moredata)
    nutherVar = func3(data3)
    #more code

    def func2(moredata):
        #WAS getting an indentation error here, until I intented
        #more code

def func3(data3):
    #now getting the indentation error here
    #more code
```

Would func2() need to be indented underneath func1() ?  Been googling but haven't found yet answer to this specific question. Obviously I'm a bad googler because this has to be easily found info. A helping hand?

### Update:

Here is the error message I get:

```
  File "w:\PyDev\SGS_ExcelPrePythonPrepAndFCode.py", line 13, in <module>
    from SGS_ExcelPrePythonPrep_funcs_ver0_01JD import *
  File "w:\PyDev\SGS_ExcelPrePythonPrep_funcs_ver0_01JD.py", line 198
    def AlphaToIndex(ltr):
      ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block
```

### Update 2:

```
modified original example pseudo-code to better represent two-file code structure
```

Comment: could you try to execute it from command line and see?

Comment: func2 can't be empty; you'll get "IndentationError: expected an indented block." Add `pass` if you that function to do nothing.

Comment: No, function definitions do not need to be indented under their calling function. Could you perhaps give more detail like the text of the error?

Comment: @JoshuaAvery - that was what I thought (and the reason for the question). I updated the question to add the error message. What's particularly weird to me is that when I double-indent the called function receiving the error, the error moves on to the next (called) function, and then to the next, etc. I'm quite new to python, but I just didn't remember having to indent called functions before.

Comment: Are you defining the functions inside the `main()` function?

Comment: In fact, the functions `func1() func2() etc` are defined inside a separate file that is imported into the main document. The structure is like this: (modifying OP). The problem is when a func() in the imported functions file calls another function defined in the imported functions file.

Comment: It would be hard for me to answer as I don't have access to the whole file.

Comment: Not a worry - thanks very much for the ideas, and especially for the confirmation that I should not have to indent called functions underneath the calling function. I'll keep fiddling with this and will post my discoveries - I've probably just gone and done something lame. *(What's super-weird and super-annoying is that everything works if I do the indents - I just don't think that's how it should work, and it will likely cause problems when I want to call one of those indented functions from a different function)*

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create an empty block you can use [`pass`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html?highlight=pass%20null#pass):

```
def func2(moredata):
    pass
```

This will create a function that does nothing (and returns `None` as any function in python with no `return`).

Comment: Yes, I realize that. Sorry, I was providing a non-runnable super-abbreviated rendition of my code structure, not runnable code. But you are right - I should have added that to make the pseudo-code more readable. Thanks for pointing that out. *(I've updated the pseudo-code sample to fix that omission)*

Answer (score 0):

Okay, Reut actually nailed the solution, despite working from the wrong data.

I had a list of functions I was writing, all code-folded up neatly:

```
func1():...
func2():...
func3():
func4():...
func5():...
```

I failed to notice that `func3()` was empty - I rabbit-trailed off to something else, intending to come right back to it, and failed to add `pass` before switching my attention.

Turns out that indenting `func4()` was not what appeared to resolve the problem with `func4()` -- at the same time I indented it, I also relocated it directly below the calling function which was above `func3()`. Then the problem appeared to move onto `func5()`.

Take-away: He who lives by code-folding, dies by code-folding. Pay attention to those ellipses!

Many thanks to Joshua Avery and Reut Sharabani who showed me where I should be looking.